# Detecting a poisoned element problem - interview question

Tags: algorithm, performance, search

Can someone walk me through their solution for this, along with the time complexity?

> You are given an array of elements, some of which are poisoned. You
> are given a function "containsPoisoned" which takes two index's, and
> will tell you if that range of elements contains poisoned elements.
> The function is very expensive, and time complexity is measured in
> number of calls to this function.
>
> ex. input= ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] (Secret, "a" and "e" are
> poisoned)
>
> containsPoisoned(0,0) => true, because 0 is poisoned
>
> containsPoisoned(2,4) => true, because 4 is poisoned
>
> containsPoisoned(1,3) => false, neither index 1, 2 or 3 is poisoned
>
> answer = ["a", "e"]

> What is the time complexity of an optimal algoriothm if you are told
> there is a single poisoned element?
>
> What is the time complexity of an optimal algorithm that could have
> any number of poisoned elements? (0, some of them, all of them, etc)

I'm not really looking for an implemented solution, just general thoughts, maybe psuedo code

Comment: Hint: binary search.

Comment: That's the direction I went as well. Binary search, in the case where every element is poisoned you end up checking the entire  "tree". The disagreement is really about the time complexity for that case

Comment: What did you conclude for the time complexity of binary search in the first case? In the second case, it's not hard to show that an algorithm with fewer than length(array) queries will not always give the right answer. There are 2^length(array) valid outputs you need to decide between.

Comment: If numPoisoned = k = 1, then binary search is log(n). I think if every node is poisoned but you attempt binary search, then it's either O(n) or O(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there is exactly one poisoned element, then you can find it using binary search in ceil(log<sub>2</sub> N) calls to `containsPoisoned`.

If any number could be poisoned, then it takes N calls to determine which ones in the worst case.  You might as well just check each element.

The proof of this is easy:

Imagine that you had a way to determine which elements are poisoned using only N-1 calls.  The information you get from those calls to `containsPoisoned` is a sequence of N-1 true/false determinations.  There are 2<sup>N-1</sup> possible sequences.

Unfortunately, there are 2<sup>N</sup> possible configurations of poisoned elements, so there are only *half* as many possible result sequences from `containsPoisoned`.  You cannot assign a unique sequence to each configuration, and so you cannot identify each configuration by the sequence it produces -- you will get a wrong answer in many cases.

Using a more sophisticated version of this proof, you can even show that if your algorithm can identify *any* configurations using less than N calls, then it will require *more* than N calls to identify some of them.